Access API protected by AWS WAF from localhost
I have set up an AWS WAF to protect my API with targeted bot control. I use the fetch wrapper AwsWafIntegration.fetch() to call the api, however when I call the API from localhost the WAF responds with a status 202 challenge that does not get handled. I presume this is because I do not have localhost in the token domain list, since if I access the api from a domain that is on the list it works as expected. I tried to remedy this by adding localhost to the list, but it is not accepted as a valid entry when I edit the list using the web console.
I have also tried getting the token directly and adding it to the headers in a normal fetch request:
headers['x-aws-waf-token'] = await AwsWafIntegration.getToken();
fetch(requestUrl, { headers });

but this did not work either.
Is there some way to get this to work so that I can use the API from localhost? Of course I could bypass the WAF for localhost but this would open a large security hole.

Were you ever able to figure this out? I have the same problem.

In the end I settled for adding an extra header that contains a secret key whenever requests were sent from localhost. Then I have the WAF accept any request with that key. Not ideal as I now have an additional secret to maintain

I'm having the same problem this week. It was working fine from localhost for like 1 or 2 months and this week I started getting this error. The solution here is the secret key?
